# cheerio node js question about table traversing

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have a simple code of this

```html
<div id="details" class="card-detail">
    <table class="card-detail-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="first">
                <th>card name</th>
                <td colspan="3">card name testing<br><span class="kana">this is not needed</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>code</th>
                <td>O3/342</td>
                <th>rarity</th>
                <td>R</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Using `cheerio`, I would like to extract 2 item from this table.

1) I would like to get the card name from the `th` and `td` column where only "card name testing" and ignore "this is not needed"

2) for the `th` with code and rarity, I would like to get their `td` value as well.

is there any way in cheerio where I can find with the `th` name such as "code" or "rarity" and proceed to take the next `td` value from there?

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JavaScript**

With vanilla JavaScript, you could use the following code to:

- Find every `th` element
- Filter out everything that does not include the string `'code'`
- Target the `nextElementSibling` (in this case, the following `td` element), and return its `innerText`

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('th')]
  .filter(el => el.innerText.includes('code'))
  .map(el => el.nextElementSibling.innerText);
```

**Cheerio / JQuery**

For Cheerio's JQuery-style syntax, I believe the equivalent is:

```
$('th')
  .filter(el => el.innerText.includes('code'))
  .map(el => el.nextElementSibling.innerText);
```

And to get the rarity, simply replace `'code'` above with `'rarity'`.

--

As for the card name, if this is always a child of `<tr class="first">`, then you can use `$('tr.first th')` to select the correct element(s).

Comment: got this error with cheerio 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Try `$('th').filter(el => el.innerText ? el.innerText.includes('code') : null).map(el => el.nextElementSibling.innerText ? el.nextElementSibling.innerText : '');
`

Answer (score 0):

after some findings, i ran with this solution instead

```
$('th').filter(function() {
    if($(this).text().trim() === 'code'){
            console.log($(this).next().text());
    }
```